# Fetching datasets from crosslinked table in a single query

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys, relational-database

Imagine the following MySQL table environment:

**admins**

```
id   username
```

**usergroups**

```
id   groupName
```

**adminXusergroup** (crosslinking table)

```
id   adminId   groupId
```

*adminId* and *groupID* are indexed **and** foreign key relations are configured accordingly (*adminId* points to **admins.id** and *groupId* points to **usergroups.id**).

All **id** fields are the primary keys.

I would like to retrieve all datasets from **usergroups** that correspond to a specific user in **admins**.

I have managed to do this in PHP by first fetching the according rows from **adminXusergroup** and then creating a list of IDs to select from **admins** in a second call. But even though it works, i feel like it can be optimized further, possibly by fetching all required information in a single MySQL query (joins perhaps?).

How can i fetch all datasets from **usergroups** that correspond to a specific dataset in **admins** (based on the id) by incorporating the information in the crosslinking table **adminXusergroup** ?

My current approach started like this:

```
SELECT * FROM usergroups WHERE usergroups.id=(SELECT id FROM adminXusergroup WHERE adminId="1");
```

But it doesn't seem right, and i am not sure as to how to apply nested selects in such a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve this using `IN` condition

```
SELECT * 
FROM usergroups 
WHERE usergroups.id IN
(
    SELECT id 
    FROM adminXusergroup 
    WHERE adminId=1
);
```

Otherwise you can use an `INNER JOIN` query

```
SELECT *
FROM usergroups a
INNER JOIN adminXusergroup b
ON a.id = b.groupId
WHERE b.adminId = 1
```

Comment: The inner join looks better to me, although i don't know why i would prefer it. Is it faster? It seems to work fine.

Comment: Well it depends on your table schema and database type, a subquery should be normally slower but if your tables doesn't have primary key/foreing key it could be slow as well with very big tables

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 SELECT a.id,u.*,x.* FROM admin as a
 INNER JOIN usergroups as u on a.id=u.id
 INNER JOIN adminXusergroup as x ON x.id=u.id WHERE u.id='userid'
```

Comment: Thank you, but this gives me an empty result.